# edit page with form that uses select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a blog like set up were there are things called events (which are essentially posts) but they have different types ("kinds") which will help me categorize where to put them in my layout. Anyway when I go to the events/edit page I get this error:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'event_kinds.event_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `event_kinds`.* FROM `event_kinds`  WHERE `event_kinds`.`event_id` = 1 LIMIT 1

I thought it might be an association issue, so is this right?

```
EventKind has_many :events
Event has_one :event_kind
```

?

EDIT:
I've renamed event_kinds to kinds. Right now I don't have a table called event_kinds that links together events and kinds models since each event can only be of one kind I just put the kind id inside the events table. Is there a way so that I can skip the events_kind...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event_id column to the event_kinds table.

Just create  a migration

rails g migration add_event_id_to_envent_kind

Edit he file and add the below content.

```
def change
  add_column :envent_kinds, :event_id, :integer
end
```

Run migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

This should solve the error.

Comment: oh... it's not that type of table though? the event_kinds table probably should be called kinds since all the kinds are unique... whoops.

Comment: hm nope, not adding the events word to the kinds table didn't work